# IFrame and Parent window

Tags: php, iframe

Can an iframe install a cookie or session on the parent page? How do i get value in an iframe to the parent page without using Ajax? I am trying to pass an Id value from the iframe to the parent page and then submit it.

Comment: Do you control both the parent and the iFrame contents? Watch out for the same origin policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy.

Comment: i can only control iframe contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within your iframe, you can reference the parent document using `parent.document`. If you had an input field in your parent window and wanted to set a value on it without using AJAX, you should simply be able to do the following using JavaScript:

```
parent.document.getElementById('myInputId').value = 'some value';
parent.document.getElementById('yourFormId').submit();
```

You can call functions in your parent page as well:

```
parent.someFunction();
```

I'm not sure about manipulating a parent's cookie(s) from a child frame, but your post it seems like all you need to do is store and submit a value. You won't be able to do it with just PHP.

Comment: I want to pass value from the iframe to the parent not the other way.. Where do i place this javascript code?

Comment: That is what this would do -- it would access the DOM of the parent (i.e. the document in which your iframe exists). This code would be included in the document you're loading in the iframe, but you'll need to heavily modify it to fit your exact needs, this isn't a copy/paste answer.

Comment: i tried inserting the code in the iframe document and making a hidden field in the parent to collect the data but it received nothing from the iframe. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should edit your post by adding your current code so we can see what you're trying to do.